# VBA macro stalls only when multiple processes not running

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that loops through a list of file paths, opening Excel workbooks and doing a few things before closing them. There are a few possible passwords associated with the workbooks, so my code tries each of them in succession, handling errors along the way.

The program works fine when I have a bunch of applications open in the background on my computer, but stalls when more of my processing power is dedicated to Excel/running the macro for some reason. It will freeze on the "opening workbook" window, so it has a password that worked, and when I cancel the action the program resumes, and still opens the workbook.

Any idea what could cause this?

> edit: here's the block that deals with opening the files:

```
...   

For Each c In fileCells

intoWorksheet.Range(itemsToPull).Copy

On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open "" & c.Value, UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, password:=****
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Workbooks.Open "" & c.Value, UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, password:=****
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Workbooks.Open "" & c.Value, UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, password:=****
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
    Workbooks.Open "" & c.Value, UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, password:=****, writerespassword:=****
End If

If Err.Number = 0 And Not intoWorksheet Is ActiveSheet Then
    Set from = ActiveWorkbook


...
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code

Comment: Just updated my post.

Comment: Also I just realized that some of the workbooks aren't actually password protected, and it seems like those are the ones causing problems. I have 7000+ files I'm going through and have run the program on all of them before without a hitch; no clue why doing it again now I'm having this problem.

Comment: Are you turning off the `On Error Resume Next` at some point?

Comment: No, do I need to be?

Comment: If there are any other errors in your code which are not specifically related to opening documents it's going to be harder to detect and fix them unless you at some point use `On Error Goto 0` (or equivalent)

Comment: It's really just the opening documents bit, the rest has been tested independently. It just hangs off and on when trying to open a workbook with an incorrect password.